# Error symbol not shown in Navigator view

Tags: java, eclipse

I use Eclipse for java development:

*Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers.
Version: Indigo Service Release 1
Build id: 20110916-0149*

Currently the *Navigator* view does not show the small error symbol (white **x** on red background) if there is a syntax error within the file.

I tested this with a small java project with a single java class. An intentionally created syntax error lead to an entry in *Problems* view and an error symbol is shown in *code view*, in *file tab* **and** in *Package Explorer*, but **not** in *Navigator* view (neither file level nor folder level).

*"Build automatically*" is activated.

Any ideas how to display the error decorator also in *Navigator* view? Is it a bug maybe? Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Imo, that's a bug. It, actually, appeared with SR1. If you reinstall the vanilla Eclipse Indigo - the error decorator would come back. It would be great, if they'd fix it, as currently it's quite annoying...

EDIT: Oook, so, oficially, it's not a bug. The intended behaviour of the Navigator view is to not display any markers related to Java code validity. The previous (long standing) state of affairs was a bug, and was fixed by this bugfix: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=291498

Unfortunately (imo) this, apparently won't change as this bug report ( https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=364660 ) was closed with RESOLVED WONTFIX.

The official suggestion is to use either Package or Project Explorer views. From my attempts to live with Project Explorer it's still not as convinient as the Navigator was, although it can be tuned to be rather close to Navigator.
I've also tried to feed Eclipse 3.7.1 with the Navigator bundles from the previous 3.7.0 release. While I'm not 100% sure it's a good solution it worked for me.

Comment: You can turn off all of the contents in the Project Explorer, except for the one that shows resources, and get the result you want.

Comment: Well, no - if you do this - there will be no error indicator throughout the folder structure - exactly as in Navigator view. The error indicators are added if you turn on Java Elements too (which is still pretty close, but clutters the view some)

Comment: Thanks for this answer, which (for python programmers) also appears with the Pydev Package Explorer but not in Navigator.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the normal behavior. I don't think it can be modified.

Comment: I'm sure that this is not normal behavior. I use Eclipse for years and there was always an error indicator within _Navigator_ view.

Comment: maybe you are confusing with `Project Explorer` view? it is pretty similar to Nav view but has the error icon.

Comment: the issue started to appear  after Indego

Answer (score 0):

I am still working with Eclipse Helios and observed the phenomenon (=no error indications) in package explorer (sic!) after removing all entries in the "problems & warnings view".
After removing the tab displaying the list of errors across all sources, the indicators reappeared again.
For me that's clearly a bug, though only a quite minor one...