# how to show eclipse error icons instead of egit icons?

Tags: java, eclipse, ide, egit

`egit` plug in for eclipse is great.

It's only drawback is that its icons hide eclipse error icons in the `navigation tree`.

How do you handle this?

see egit icons:

[image]

Comment: Could you provide screenshot of that.

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/q/7822152/1700321.