# Syntax error not shown in eclipse kepler Navigator view

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-kepler

I am using eclipse kepler. In that for any syntax error in file it won't show me error mark in Navigator view. Is there any settings which I need to change specific to eclipse kepler?
Note: For same project it works in eclipse helios.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/q/7822152/1700321.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Navigator view is no longer supported in eclipse so no bugs are fixed for it in all releases starging from Indigo

Comment: This was the case raised for eclipse Indigo but resolved as won't fix
https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=364660

Answer (score 0):

Do the following:

1. Check project properties
2. Check build path and check everything is OK
3. Try to change builder (move from java builder to maven builder or vice-versa)
4. Refresh navigator
5. Try to remove some semicolons, save and then put it again

Often it works for me ...

Answer (score 0):

try to delete this folder: 
[your worskpace].metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.e4.workbench
It'll work

Answer (score -3):

1,project -->> clean;

2,project -->>build automatically select

3,If the above two programs can not solve your problem, please go to the official website to download an Eclipse version