# Eclipse Luna - No error icon shown in Navigator view

Tags: java, eclipse

I recently installed Eclipse Luna on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

For some reason the Navigator view shows no red cross icons to indicate errors. The icons are shown in the Project and Package views. I've looked through the view preferences but there appears to be no config parameter which controls the visibility of this icon.

This used to work in my previous Eclipse version (Helios).

However after scouring the web I can find nothing recent, related to this.

Anyone else getting this problem with Luna? Is this now normal behaviour for the Navigator view?

Thanks

Comment: I see the same behavior in kepler too. I generally use `project explorer` to see errors.

Comment: Sadly, it is normal behavior. See http://stackoverflow.com/q/7822152/1700321.

Comment: Thanks. @Aleksandr post your comment as an answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sadly, it is *normal* behavior for quite some time now. There is a bug resolved as `WONTFIX` - https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=364660.

Below is some comments from this bug:

> A little bit of explanation here. Having the decorations in navigator in Eclipse prior to Indigo SR1 was caused by using a wrong class as a problem decorator in java ee plugins. Further more the decorations were available only in Java EE distribution of eclipse (because of the location where the problem decorator definition was).
>
> You can check for more details here: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=291498

And

> ...note that the 'Navigator' view is no longer actively worked on and we, the Platform UI team, have no plans to add new features to that view.